# Opencart v1.4.8 - Product Page Broken / Charset Encoding

Tags: php, character-encoding, e-commerce, opencart, product

I have a problem with a site at the moment, it's been migrated over to a new server, all the pages working fine except the product page. I get this weird character set encoding on the page. Character set is set to UTF-8.

Now the product page works on the live website: http://www.officeking.com/officeking-ce285a-com-black-toner-cartridge but doesnt work on the new server link: http://officeking.flyingatom.co.uk/officeking-ce505x-com-high-capacity-black-toner-cartridge

I'm no opencart expert so any guidance/assistance would be very much appreciated. If you require anymore information then just reply back.

[Error Log](http://jpst.it/zVpP)

The error log is the same for the live website officeking.com but the product page loads fine. The temp URL doesnt seem to load it.

Any idea's as to what is going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello , Did you fix the problem? i dont see any weird char encoding and the 2-nd link just doesn work at all

Comment: @Innervisions nope didn't fix the problem, are you able to help? 2nd link is to a product and the page doesn't seem to load. How weird that the encoding crap has disappeared. Maybe some weird caching?

Comment: It's probably caching yeah,but for your 2-nd link check all your config.php files and make sure the right paths are selected

Comment: Also try to go into admin ->system-> settings and see the SEO URLS turn it off and see if the products work sometimes,that thing is causing issues,also turn of the G-zip from admin ->system-> settings  ,and check your .htaccess file,it could be causing issues aswell

Comment: @innervisions I can't log into the CMS - I get failed to get token error or something along those lines. So can't get into administration area to make the changes :(

Comment: Sounds like config.php files issue

1-st link is your old domain
2-nd one is the new domain right?

Comment: @innervisions first domain is the live working website and the second is a test domain setup on a new server. Is the config file in the root or administration folder that needs fixing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82263/discussion-between-innervisions-and-mjcoder).

Comment: @innervisions I'll be in the office in 20mins or so and we can continue this discussion in chat if that's OK with you?

Comment: @Innervisions i'm free to head over to the discussions section to chat if you are free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a long discussion in the chat with MJCoder

For anyone else that might have this issue

The product pages not showing up it was because the Gzip compression was turned on
in

`admin->system->settings->server and set it to 0.`

Comment: also to add, i then enabled gZip compression in the .htaccess file and it worked! Cheers @innervisions